# Electric Bell Quiz with IC

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design

I have a quiz bell circuit electrically. When one bell is pressed, the LED will light and bell other will not work.

The problem is when bell is pressed simultaneously, then the other LED will also light as well. I've done a simulation by Multisim.
[image]

This is the project link
[Quiz Bell](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4MsDm09nNPJcnVxRl8yaVYzcGM)

Can anyone analyze where the mistakes of this circuit?. Thank you

Comment: Are you also creating the simultaneous switch closures with the simulator? That simultaneous condition will most likely never happen in a real life.  The simulator can easily flip multiple switches before the feedback signal locks out the other inputs. If the simulator allows it try closing the other switches about 1 microsecond later, this would be closer to a real conditions with a human commanding each switch.

Answer (score 1):

You can put in something like this after the outputs of the 7475 latches as tie-breaker.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fliPDy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The gates are 4-input NAND gates. The latches may still latch on to more than one press, but the "tie-breaker" will resolve to only one negative true output.

Comment: It still not works. This is the new circuit [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4MsDm09nNPJeTd6ZTdkelowU28)

Comment: When you say it does not work, do you mean it still gives more than one negative true output? I don't see how that can happen (although if the arrival time of two presses are perfectly match, some oscillation is possible, but things are just not so balance that the oscillation can last). By the way, the U5A that is for generating the latch signal should take the inputs directly from the 7475 as before. That keeps the latching time window as short as possible. Also, with your new schematics, it seems to indication VCC is 9V, that would far exceed the specs of 74LS TTL.

Comment: okay, when i simulate my new schematics with proteus it is work. When button pressed, LED will stay ON (the fastest one) and simultaneous condition not happen. But i still dont know, when i simulate it with multisim,why it is not work. So thank you. Then, about the vcc 9v, when i change it to 5v, the LED wont active. So i change it to 9v.